# Get the count from the sql query in moodle

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I am trying to fetch the number of rows for a query using a Moodle function.

This is what I have done so far:

```
$records = $DB->get_records_sql("select * from {user} where maildigest=$login_id");
```

How do I get the number of results?

Comment: Have you tried `count(*)` Mysql function ?

Comment: This method returns an array, so all you need to to is `count` the elements of the array ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_records_sql()](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Getting_an_hashed_array_of_records) retruns an array, so use `count()` to get number of records.

Do like below:-

```
$records=$DB->get_records_sql("select * from {user} where maildigest=$login_id");

echo (count($records));
```

Link section you have to refer:- https://prnt.sc/gpggq4

Comment: I would not recommend any solution that involves inserting arbitrary values into SQL statements like that - you are asking for SQL injection attacks. The answer by Aldo Paradiso, is the correct solution.

Comment: @davosmith  i don't think so, because his code is as much vulnerable as mine. `array('maildigest'=>$login_id)` will not insure `prevention`. BTW have no issue. Thanks

Comment: Yes it will, as Moodle DB functions will clean and escape every param added that way, simply using string insertion as shown here leaves you open to malicious SQL

Comment: @AlivetoDie hii have one doubt

Comment: @user200  please ask a new question if you have any doubt. Thanks

Comment: i already asked..can you please look at that here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765498/show-the-error-message-while-uploading-excel-file-data-in-db-if-user-already-exi/46765972?noredirect=1#comment80482745_46765972

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Moodle specific function to count records:

```
$DB->count_records($table);
```

In your case you can use:

```
echo $DB->count_records('user', array('maildigest'=>$login_id));
```

This function has been designed to improve efficiency: you do not need to retrieve a whole bunch of data if you just want to count the retrieved records;-)