# Show the error message while uploading Excel file data to database if user already exist in PHP

Tags: php, excel, moodle

I am trying to use the `phpexcel` library for loading some Excel data in to a database and everything is working fine if the user already exists - it's not showing any error.

How do I show an error message if a user already exists in the database?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    require('../config.php');
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    $inputFileName = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
    try {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
    $arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);
    $ref = 1;
    $today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $arrayCount; $i++) {
        $username = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
        $firstname = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
        $lastname = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["C"]);
        $email = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["D"]);
        $password = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["E"]);
        if ($username != '' || $username != 0) {
            $insert_record = new stdClass();
            $insert_record->username = $username;
            $insert_record->email = $email;

            $insert_record->firstname = $firstname;
            $insert_record->lastname = $lastname;

            $insert_record->password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $insert_record->idnumber = 1;
            $insert_record->timecreated = time();
            $insert_record->mnethostid = 1;
            $insert_record->confirmed = 1;
            $resultcheck = $DB->insert_record('user', $insert_record);
        }
    }
    header("Location:user_management.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $arrayCount; $i++) {
        ...
        $resultcheck = $DB->insert_record('user', $insert_record);
        if ($resultcheck == false){
           header("Location:error.php");
        }

}
```

OR if you are able to use jQuery/AJAX

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $arrayCount; $i++) {
        ...
        $resultcheck = $DB->insert_record('user', $insert_record);
        if ($resultcheck == false){
           echo json_encode ('Your Error Message.');
           exit ();
        }

}
```

Maybe you could add some check in your DB class

```
public function insert_record($table, $insert_record) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username =: username";

$statement = $this->db->prepare ( $sql );

$statement->bindValue ( ':username', $insert_record->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );

$statement->execute ();

$result = $statement->fetch ( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

if (count($result) > 0){
    return false;
}

    // Do your other stuff here         

}
```

Comment: What does print_r($resultcheck) return?

Comment: sometimes it storing the header values in db..from xl file

Comment: $resultcheck is an Array like `Array ('column1' => 'id', 'column2' => 'name')`? then you can check the length of the Array with `Count($resultcheck)`. Maybe this helps.

Comment: no i am trying like select * fom table name where username=$allDataInSheet[$i] ;when this query happenes i have to make error message

Comment: Could provide us your database handling code, please? I have edited my answer with one possible way to check if the user already exists.

Comment: if do you have idea with moodle..i am using the moodle db only

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with moodle.

Comment: it's okay..thanq for help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple paths to solve the problem. It depends on your actual code.

If you set the username field as unique in your database and you're using PDO queries, you can't try and catch the error code:

```
  try{
     //Make the insert
  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
     if($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062){
       //Duplicated
     }
     else{
       //Other errors...
     }
  }
```

Comment: i used  like this

Comment: try {
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
 
    if($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062){
       echo "duplicated";
     }else{
      die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($inputFileName, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": ' . $e->getMessage());
     }

Comment: i tried like that..its not working..actually i connected this project to moodle..

Comment: Try block should be the insert related code (query) instead the excel code.